# Select all rows that have '_' in a given column

Tags: sql-server

I want to select the rows that have a  '_' character in a given column from SQL.
when I try to run this query, it returns all the rows in the table

```
SELECT * FROM [Attribute] where LibID=26 and Name like '%_%'
```

but the following query yields what I need

```
SELECT * FROM [Attribute] where LibID=26 and CHARINDEX('_', Name) > 0
```

why my first query is not returning expected result. Maybe I am missing some information/knowledge of SQL.

Comment: like '%\\_%' ESCAPE  '\'

Answer (score 3):

The `_` (underscore) character is used by the LIKE function to match any character. If you want to use it as an underscore, you need to escape it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Attribute] 
where LibID=26 
and Name like '%[_]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The underscore is a wildcard character in a LIKE query. It indicates any single character.

To use the LIKE syntax, use:

`SELECT * FROM [Attribute] where LibID=26 and Name like '%[_]%'`